# comparing files and writing only matching patterns, perl or awk?

Tags: perl, awk

I need to compare two files. In a first file I have some ID pairs, in a second file I have the ID list written in two styles (one per column). They look like this:

**file 1**

```
IDnew_1 IDnew_2
IDnew_3 IDnew_4
IDnew_5 IDnew_6
IDnew_7 IDnew_8
```

**file 2**

```
IDnew_1 IDold_1
IDnew_2 IDold_2
IDnew_7 IDold_7
IDnew_8 IDold_8
```

I would like to obtain an output like this:

```
IDold_1 IDold_2
IDold_7 IDold_8
```

Pratically I need to "translate" the file 1 in "old style IDs that are in the file two.
I tried something in `perl`, but I'm not able to work with two columns in file 2.
My perl code looks like this:

```
$file_GS = "file1.txt";
$file_orto = "file2.txt";
open (HAN, "< $file_orto") || die "Impossible open input orto";
@r = <HAN>;
close (HAN);
open (GAS, "< $file_GS") || die "Immposible open GS file";
@p = <GAS>;
close (GAS);

for ($i=0; $i<=$#r; $i++){
chomp ($r[$i]);
@orto = split ( /\t/, $r[$i]);
$old = $orto[0];
$new = $orto[1];

for ($l=0; $l<=$#p; $l++){
chomp ($p[$l]);
@v = split (/\t/, $p[$l]);
$gs1 = $v[0];
$gs2 = $v[1];

if ($gs1 eq pf_old){
print "$pb\n";
}
}
}
```

This code writes only one column and the output looks like this:

```
IDold_1
IDold_7
```

....how can I make it working giving me both columns of output?
Suggestions?
Thank you!!

Comment: Please show us your Perl code.

Comment: in output there is no data from file1?

Comment: @mpapec in output I've the IDs equivalent to the IDs in file 1 (new IDs "translated" in old IDs).

Comment: Your question is not clear at all, There are many ways to produce the expected output using just `file2` alone. Please edit your question with more representative data and clearly described the transformation you require.

Comment: @sudo_O if both IDs of a row in 'File 1' (i.e. IDnew_1 IDnew_2) have the correspondent old ID in 'File 2' (IDnew_1 IDold_1; IDnew_2 IDold_2), I want this ID pair saved in the output as old IDs (IDold_1 IDold_2). Otherwise I don't want any output. Sorry, but I'm not a programmer...so my technical knowledge is very poor!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, hash the "translation" file. Then just print those lines for which a translation of both ids is found.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $file_gs   = 'file1.txt';
my $file_orto = 'file2.txt';

my %translate;
open my $ORTO, '<', $file_orto or die $!;
while (<$ORTO>) {
    my ($new, $old) = split;
    die "Duplicate $old" if exists $translate{$old};
    $translate{$new} = $old;
}

open my $GS, '<', $file_gs or die $!;
while (<$GS>) {
    my @ids = grep defined, map $translate{$_}, split;
    print "@ids\n" if 2 == @ids;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You've got to give a better explanation what you want.

My assumption is that you want to use File #2 as a look up table. That is, you have a new ID in File #1, and you need to convert it to the old Id found in file #2. Is this correct? What if a line in File #1 has a convertible ID in column #1, but not column #2? What do you want?

In this case, you would want to read in File #2 first, and make a hash translating from the New ID (the key) to the old ID (the data).

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);
use autodie;

use constant {
    FILE_1    => "file1.txt",
    FILE_2    => "file2.txt",
};

# Read in File 2 and create a look up table
open my $file2_fh, "<", FILE_2;
my %lookup_table;

while ( my $line = <$file2_fh> ) {
    chomp $line;
    my ($new_id, $old_id) = split /\s+/, $line;
    $lookup_table{ $new_id } = $old_id;
}
close $file2_fh;
```

Now that you have a look up table, you can easily translate from the new ID to the old ID. Let'e go through File #1

```
open my $file1_fh, "<", FILE_1;
while ( my $line = <$file1_fh> ) {
    chomp $line;
    my ($new_id_1, $new_id_2 ) = split /\s+/, $line;

    my ( $old_id_1, $old_id_2 );

    if ( exists $lookup_table{ $new_id_1 } ) {
       $old_id_1 = $lookup_table{ $new_id_1 };
    }

    if ( exists $lookup_table{ $new_id_2 } ) {
       $old_id_2 = $lookup_table{ $new_id_2 };
    }

    # Now you've got to decide what to do here...

    # First column is defined and second column isn't
    if    ( defined $old_id_1 and not defined $old_id_2 ) {
        say "Here be dragons...";
    }
    # Second column is defined and first column isn't
    elsif ( not defined $old_id_1 and defined $old_id_2 ) {
        say "Here be dragons...";
    }
    # Both columns are defined
    elsif ( defined $old_id_1 and defined $old_id_2 ) {
        say "$old_id_1   $old_id_2";
    }
}
close $file1_fh;
```

Comment: I think your code is amazing, but to hard for me. My programming is too poor to manage it properly... I tried it, but I get a lot of errors that I cannot understand... :(

Comment: I tested this program with the data you gave. It's a direct cut and paste of what I used.