# Compare files and write matching and not matching things

Tags: perl

I'm a very new in programming and need a lot of help. I have two files:

the first one reports a column with some IDs (pratically a list) and looks like this:

```
ID_3
ID_6
ID_5-2
ID_38
```

the second file reports a table with several columns and look like this:

```
name1 ID_1 ID_1-2
name2 ID_2 ID_2-2
name3 ID_3 ID_3-2 ID_3-3
name4 ID_4
name5 ID_5 ID_5-2
name6 ID_6
```

My aim is to compare each ID in the first file with the IDs reported in the second. If there is a match I want to print the respective *name* (for example, for *ID_3* in file 1 I want to print *name3* in the output), if there is no match I want to print the not matching ID from file 1 qith "not-found". For example for *ID_38* (that doesn't have a match in file 2) I want to print *ID_38 not-found*.

I wrote a perl script that is able to write correctly the *names* corresponding to the matching IDs, but it's not able to write the not matching IDs in a good way.
The code looks like this:

```
$file_table = "file_2.txt";
$file_list = "file1.txt";
open (HAN, "< $file_table") || die "Impossible open the table";
@r = <HAN>;
close (HAN);
open (PEW, "< $file_list") || die "Impossible open the list";
@l = <PEW>;
close (PEW);
for ($p=0; $p<=$#l; $p++) {
   chomp ($l[$p]);
   for ($i=0; $i<=$#r; $i++) {
     chomp ($r[$i]);
     @v = split (/ /, $r[$i]);
     for ($j=0; $j<=$#v; $j++) {
       chomp ($v[$j]);
       if ($l[$p] eq $v[$j]) {
         print "$v[0]\n";
       } else {
         print "$l[$p] not-found\n";
       }
     }
   }
}
```

I get wrong and too much "not-found" lines in the output and I don't know how to solve. I desire an output like this:

```
name3
name6
name5
ID_38
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a hash to remember what ID corresponds to what name.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $table  = 'file_2.txt';
my $column = 'file1.txt';

my %names;
open my $TAB, '<', $table or die $!;
while (<$TAB>) {
    my ($name, @ids) = split;
    push @{ $names{$_} }, $name for @ids;
}

open my $COL, '<', $column or die $!;
while (<$COL>) {
    chomp;
    print @{ $names{$_} // [$_] }, "\n";
}
```

Comment: ...one more question: what about if the input list has two columns?

Comment: @Gabelins: What is in the second column, then?

Comment: a second column, same length of the first, with IDs. Like (the comma to separate rows): ID_3 ID_3-2, ID_6 ID_5, ID_5-2 ID_2-2, ID_38 ID_1. In the case of a row in which there is a matching ID and a not matching ID I don't want any output.

Comment: @Gabelins: You should probably post a new question with the full specification.

Comment: I posted this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16855980/comparing-files-and-writing-only-matching-patterns-perl-or-awk